# php replace text in msword using COM

Tags: php, vba, com

I'm trying to use php replace texts in msword doc. Using COM. 
throws Error [0x80020011] Does not support a collection.
code is copy and modified from VBA.

```
       $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die("Word not installed!");
        try{
            $word->Documents->Open("c:\1.doc");
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Text="222";
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Replacement->Text="111";
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Forward=True;
            //$word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Replace=2;
            //$word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Wrap=1;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Format=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->MatchCase=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->MatchWholeWord=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->MatchWildcards=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->MatchSoundsLike=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->MatchAllWordForms=False;
            $word->ActiveDocument->Range->Find->Execute();
            $word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs("c:\2.doc");
            $word->Quit();
       }
       .....
```

**another way**

```
   $wdFindContinue = 1;
   $wdReplaceAll = 2;
   $word->ActiveDocument->Content->Find->Execute("222", false, false, false, false, false, true, $wdFindContinue, false, "111", $wdReplaceAll);
```

the server is using office 2007, and php 4.6 /apache 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update:

Do not use it in php , it won't replace all the strings.

**another solution:**

1. save word as **xml**
2. then use **php fread** to open it as text
3. **replace strings** inside.

and save to file.